# Cant install wine1.5 13.04

Tags: installation, wine, package-management

So I tried to install wine 1.5 a few times, I got 1.4 installed, and 1.6 installed oddly enough, I completely removed and purged all wine and still nothing. I installed ia32-lib and still nothing, tried installing from synaptic, ubuntu software center, and apt-get method. I get this error from apt-get in the terminal

```
Reading package lists... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The particular windows program I want to install is confirmed working in 1.5(have it working on laptop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install just the ppa wine & any deps from a console

1st. remove the metapackage if installed

`sudo apt-get purge wine`

Then same commands whether wine is or isn't installed

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

Finish with

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine`

If you have any concerns, you can simulate, (-s) the install by going

`sudo apt-get -s install wine`

If all is well just re-run without -s.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using 1.6 version, could not get 1.5 working, but 1.6 is doing fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. Drove me crazy. Ended up running:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then, quick update:

```
apt-get Update
```

And it appears to be installing now.

Comment: I don't see how adding the `i386` architecture can help.